# How can I access to the documentation of previous MATLAB releases without creating a MathWorks account?

Tags: matlab, documentation, licensing

The [Archived MathWorks Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) for Matlab on MathWorks website requires to be logged in. Is there any way to have access to the documentation of previous MATLAB releases without creating a MathWorks account?

Comment: what's more, accessing latest documentation of some toolboxes require an account with an associated active license for those products... I'm not a fan of hiding docs behind login portals :(

Comment: Wow I wasn't aware of that. Can you please give one toolbox as example? (btw, better than docs behind login portals, [standards behind paywall](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/658965/24265))

Comment: you can go through the list of toolboxes [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/) and see which ones you can access.. For instance I am not able to see the docs for "MATLAB Production Server" using my account.

Comment: While this is not a programming question, it's sort of issues that are integral part of messing with this SW, and is in the main interesting field of Matlab users. I think that closing this question by people who has nothing with Matlab is not professional, EVEN if the strict laws of SO indicate to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, it requires a account which is connected to a full license. With most student licenses, you can't access the archive.

Comment: Thanks, contrary to what they say on the website, it doesn't seem require a account which is connected to a full license. I was hoping for some unofficial websites mirroring the docs.

Comment: You are right. I tried it shortly after creating the account and was unable to open the documentation. Now it is possible, using my student license.

Comment: Btw I asked why we need to be logged in to access the Archived MathWorks Documentation on MATLAB Newsgroup: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/333798

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: the newsgroup is getting less popular these days, you might wanna try your question on [MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) which is frequented by MathWorks employees.

Comment: @Amro Thanks, done: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/114594-why-do-i-need-to-be-logged-in-to-access-the-archived-mathworks-documentation

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/114594-why-do-i-need-to-be-logged-in-to-access-the-archived-mathworks-documentation?s_tid=gn_loc_drop :

> Answer by Walter Roberson  on 2 Feb 2014:
>
> Archived documentation is only available to people on support contracts.
>
> I could $peculate about reason$ for the policy, but it would be pure $peculation.